# struct pointer and void pointer confusion while doing malloc

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct data
{
    int *data_array;
    int *thread_number;
}array;
....
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

...
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    array  *array_ptr;
    array_ptr->data_array = malloc((size+2)*sizeof(int));//failing line
....
}
```

because of the failing line  it gives me seg. fault 
how must solve it

Answer (score 4):

In your code,

```
array  *array_ptr;
array_ptr->data_array = malloc((size+2)*sizeof(int));//failing line
```

`array_ptr` itself is used uninitialized. If you try to dereference an unitialized pointer, you'll invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the many *effects* of UB.

You should allocate memory to `array_ptr` first, like

```
array  *array_ptr = NULL;
array_ptr = malloc(sizeof *array_ptr);
if (array_ptr)                           //check for malloc success
{
    array_ptr->data_array = malloc((size+2)*sizeof(int));
.....
}
else
{
    printf("failure\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a local variable like this

```
array  *array_ptr;
```

`array_ptr` pointer is given a place in memory, but it does not point to a valid `array` struct in memory: the value of uninitialized variable contains some random "garbage" value. Therefore, dereferencing it in any way, including

```
array_ptr->data_array = malloc ...
```

is *undefined behavior*.

You can fix it by allocating some memory to the `array` pointed to by `array_ptr`, like this:

```
array  *array_ptr = malloc(sizeof(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault is  expected as you have not created any memory for **array_ptr** and you are trying to reference it which eventually will try to access the data_array(for which there is no memory yet ) So , kernel will signal the process to terminated and hence you will get segmentation fault here .

```
int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    array  *array_ptr;
    array_ptr->data_array = malloc((size+2)*sizeof(int));//failing line
```

However , to fix this , you shold first create memory for array_ptr .

```
array  *array_ptr = (array * )malloc(sizeof(array));//type casting is necessary as malloc returns pointer to void .
```

After this you can check the pointer and assign memory to its data members

```
  if(array_ptr )
{
    array_ptr->data_array = malloc((size+2)*sizeof(int));//type cast here also 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int size = atoi(argv[1]); 
    array *array_ptr;
array_ptr->data_array = (*int) malloc(sizeof(int)*(size+2));
```

Works?

-- Edit --

I get the number from argv and transform in int.
Create the structute.
I create the memory whith the size than a int plus (arg + 2), and associate this in the struct, only

Comment: It would be great if you explain a how this code works and what was the problem in OP's code. :)

Comment: Edited... Verify if this is the solution (i make a cast only for convert void* to int* )